# How To override the ui-component ViewAction.php in module-sales/Ui/Component/Listing/Column

Tags: magento2, overrides, uicomponent

I want to add another action in the grid for the sales in Magento back end

The actions are defined in `modules-sales\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\ViewAction.php`

So i want to override this file , But how can i override ?

Comment: Did you try with DI?

Comment: How do you do it with the DI.xml ?

Comment: Take a look my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) We can build our own View Action class by "overriding" the action column.

*app/code/Vendor/Sales/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">

    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <actionsColumn name="actions" class="Vendor\Sales\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\ViewAction">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                    <item name="viewUrlPath" xsi:type="string">sales/order/view</item>
                    <item name="urlEntityParamName" xsi:type="string">order_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </actionsColumn>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Build our own view Action class: `app/code/Vendor/Sales/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/ViewAction.php`

2) Or can override `Magento\Sales\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\ViewAction` class. (Not test yet, but not recommend)

*app/code/Vendor/Sales/etc/di.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\ViewAction"
                type="Vendor\Sales\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\ViewAction" />
</config>
```

Comment: You tried with 2nd solution?

Comment: Nope , I didn't try it

Comment: Ha..ha.. I will try it myself.

Comment: If I want to change label of column from ID to Order# then what to do? @KhoaTruongDinh